# In LINQ, what is the difference between Join and selecting the first item from a nested query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, join

Here's some LINQ to select all order details. It creates a join with the product table to get the product name:

```
var query = from od in db.Order_Details
            join p in db.Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
            select new { od.OrderID, od.ProductID, p.ProductName };
```

Here's how I would do it if I didn't know that Join existed:

```
var query = from od in db.Order_Details
            select new { od.OrderID, 
                         od.ProductID, 
                         ProductName = (from p in db.Products 
                                        where p.ProductID == od.ProductID 
                                        select p.ProductName).First()
            };
```

They generate different underlying SQL code. Is the first method faster than the second, and if so why?

**ETA:**

db.Log for join query:

```
SELECT [t0].[OrderID], [t0].[ProductID], [t1].[ProductName]
FROM [dbo].[Order Details] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ProductID] = [t1].[ProductID]
```

db.Log for 2nd query:

```
SELECT [t0].[OrderID], [t0].[ProductID], (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[ProductName]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ProductID] = [t0].[ProductID]
    ) AS [ProductName]
FROM [dbo].[Order Details] AS [t0]
```

Comment: What does your profiler say? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the profiler is but I'll add the output of db.Log to my post...

Comment: A profiler is a tool that measures code performance.  Your actual performance will depend on many factors, like whether or not the join fields are indexed in the underlying data store, and how much data is in the tables.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm hoping that this kind of thing has been profiled many times before dating back to the pre-linq, pure sql days.

Comment: You can take your generated query, run it against your database in SQL Server Management Studio with "Display Execution Plan" enabled to see which one is more performant.

Comment: Joins are generally "safer" than sub-queries.  usually faster as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joins are typically faster than equivalent nested selects since DBMS' are very good at optimizing joins, although a good SQL compiler might optimize them to the same SQL anyway. You should use the one which makes your purpose more clear, which is probably the join in this case.

Comment: As you can see from the SELECT statements that were posted in the question, neither the C# compiler nor LINQ-to-SQL performed any kind of optimization [applies to first revision of answer]. The database's query optimizer, though, could easily handle such a case and probably has identical performance characteristics for both queries. LINQ-to-Objects, on the other hand, does not have a query optimizer and may suffer from such a nested query.

Answer (score 1):

The second example you provide without the join does what is called a "correlated subquery", and is generally going to be slower than a join.  The results are the same, but the difference is the performance of getting those results.  You should favor the join.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx